# Changing Names Of The Logical Entities to the Title Case (Oracle SDDM)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Is there a way to apply the naming conventions to the model created in Oracle SDDM to change the logical names of the Entities and Attributes to the title case?

We are doing the reverse engineering of the data model and kind of not finding the option. Do we need to manage it using the abbreviations file?

Comment: You may need a transformation script, I'll try to look at this on Monday

Comment: Done Thanks very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: Finally understood what you have referred to as a custom transformation script. Created the same in the Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Answer (score 1):

Custom Transformation Script in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler -

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w+/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}

tables = model.getEntitySet().toArray();
for (var t = 0; t<tables.length;t++){
 table = tables[t];
 name = toTitleCase(table.getName());
 table.setName(name);
 columns = table.getElements();
 size = table.getElementsCollection().size();
 for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    column = columns[i];
    cname = toTitleCase(column.getName());
    column.setName(cname);
 }
 table.setDirty(true);
 keys = table.getKeys();
 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  key = keys[i];
    if(!key.isFK()){
     kname = toTitleCase(key.getName());
     key.setName(kname);
   }else{
     kname = toTitleCase(key.getFKAssociation().getName());
     key.getFKAssociation().setName(kname);
     key.getFKAssociation().setDirty(true);
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote the following code in Powershell, for Changing Names Of The Logical Entities And Attributes to the Title Case in Oracle SDDM -

```
$Culture = Get-Culture
# Path to the XML File
$directoryPath = "<Path to the Data Modeling Design>\logical\entity\seg_0"

function Change-Name-To-Title-Case
{

    Param (    
        [parameter (Mandatory=$true, position=1, ParameterSetName='XML File Path')]
        [string]$FilePath
        )
    [XML] $XmlDocument = ( Select-Xml -Path $FilePath  -XPath / ).Node

    [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings] $XmlSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings

    #Preserve Windows formating
    $XmlSettings.Indent = $true

    #Keeping UTF-8 without BOM
    $XmlSettings.Encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($false)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Modify the Element - Entity Value
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    $elem_entity =  $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Entity")
    $elem_entity.Name = ($Culture.textinfo.totitlecase(($elem_entity.Name).ToLower()))
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Modify the Entity - Attributes Value
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    $elem_attributes =  $XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Attribute")
    foreach ($elem_attribute in $elem_attributes ){
            $elem_attribute.Name = ($Culture.textinfo.totitlecase(($elem_attribute.Name).ToLower()))
    }
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Save the File
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    [System.Xml.XmlWriter] $XmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($FilePath, $XmlSettings)
    $XmlDocument.Save($XmlWriter)

    #Close Handle and flush
    $XmlWriter.Dispose()
}

Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -Filter *.xml |
Foreach-Object {
  Change-Name-To-Title-Case -FilePath $_.FullName
}
```